# What happens if you return a non-static local when the return type is static const

Tags: c++, static, constants

If you have the following function:

```
static const map<ushort, ulong> MakeMap()
{
  map<ushort, ulong> mymap;
  for(int i=0; i<myTableSize; i++)
  {
    mymap[myTable[i].x] = myTable[i].y;
  }
  return mymap;
}
```

and somewhere use you have:

```
static const map<ushort, ulong> numMap = MakeMap();
```

will the compiler actually set numMap to the address returned from MakeMap or will it actually make a copy of the map?  Also, is this even safe to do?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: The return type isn't "static const", it's a static function that returns a const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type is not `static const map<ushort, ulong>`. It's only `const map<ushort, ulong>`. The keyword `static` applies to the function. That is, it's the function which is static which means the function has [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)<sup>*</sup> and cannot be called from other [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* Go through the links to know about them.</sup>

Now coming back to your question, first of all, `const` in the return type doesn't make sense. The following is better:

```
//remove the static also if you don't want it to have internal linkage
static map<ushort, ulong> MakeMap();
```

And then you can still write:

```
 const map<ushort, ulong> numMap = MakeMap();
```

If you're using good compiler, then most likely it will optimize on the return value. Read about:

- [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to do this. For most practical purposes, the code will behave as if a copy were made (a good optimizing compiler [may eliminate the need for an actual copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025899/when-should-rvo-kick-in)).

Also, as others have pointed out, `static` isn't part of the return type. The two uses of `static` in your code have different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning an address but on object which will be copied so it's safe to do so. If you modify your code so MakeMap return an address , then mymapy will be destroyed at some point (depending of compilation options and compiler) and so that will crash. You have to allocate mymap on the heap (with a new) and then destroy it etc ....