# Return value optimization (RVO) when using temporaries in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have two functions A and B.

where function A returns an object X and function B gets object X as an argument. For example.

```
X A() {
    X x;
    return x;
}

void B(X x) {
    write(x.data, x.size);
}

int main() { B(A()); }
```

Is this object X constructed only once as a temporary of B using RVO or do I need to use move semantics.

Comment: The answer will most likely be dependent on your compiler.  Do you have a particular compiler in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If copy elision is used, the X will only be constructed once.

Even if copy elision is disabled (e.g. passing the `-fno-elide-constructors` to gcc), the move constructors will be used automatically.

You can visualize it yourself:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct X
{
    X() { printf("default constructed\n"); }
    ~X() { printf("destructed\n"); }
    X(const X&) { printf("copy constructed\n"); }
    X(X&&) { printf("move constructed\n"); }
};

X A() {
    X x;
    return x;
}

void B(X x) {

}

int main() {
    B(A());
}
```

With RVO it prints

```
default constructed
destructed
```

With no RVO it prints

```
default constructed
move constructed
destructed
move constructed
destructed
destructed
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is only *allowed* to perform RVO, but *not obliged* to by the standard. Hence, it may or may not optimise your code, entirely depending on the compiler used and its parameters.

Another question might help with related details: [When should RVO kick-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025899/when-should-rvo-kick-in)

Comment: I think it's a requirement in C++11, but even if it wasn't, no sane compiler implementing rvalue references and move semantics will *not* have it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: C++11 doesn't require RVO either - it requires that the return value is moved rather than copied if RVO is not used.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Ah well, it's close enough.

Answer (score 1):

It will most probably be the same object (i.e. no extra copy will be created). This isn't RVO though, it's called copy elision.

The quote is not from C++11, but C++03:

**12.2/2 Temporary objects**

> Here, an implementation might use a temporary in which to construct X(2) before passing it to f()  using X's copy-constructor; alternatively, X(2) might be constructed in the space used to hold the argument. /.../

Comment: RVO and copy elision is the same thing. (Or: RVO is one instance of copy elision.)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus RVO is an instance of copy elision, but that doesn't make them the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so how does RVO and copy elision differ?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: copy elision is a scenario where a copy of the object can be elided(omitted) by the compiler, RVO is the most commonly known use case of copy elision, but compilers can elide copies of object in scenarios other than returning temporaries.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I'm guessing RVO only applies to eliding copies related to the return from a function. I've no theoretical backing on this, it's just what the name return value optimization suggests.

Comment: @Als: "Or: RVO is one instance of copy elision." Because copy elision is more general term doesn't mean RVO isn't copy elision, or that RVO isn't used here.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I never said RVO isn't copy elision. It is, I agree with that. I just said copy elision isn't RVO. It's like saying Toyota is a car (true) and car is a Toyota (false).

Comment: Yes, but in this instance it *is* RVO. Value returned from `A()` is constructed directly into the argument of `B()`. Maybe my wording wasn't very good.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: No I didnt mean or imply that RVO is not copy elision, ofcourse it is just RVO is not the only copy elision there can be other cases, Also I didn't mean to imply there is no RVO here, I seem to have misinterpreted your comment in that case.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I'm guessing this is a discussion where we're all saying the same thing in different terms, and it only appears we're contradicting. :)

Comment: Yeah, let's leave it at that. :P

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I don't have any authoritative source, but my understanding is that in `type f() { type x; return x; } int main() { type y( f() ); }` the elision of the copy in the return statement (`return x;`) is NRVO (if it was just `return type();` it would be plain RVO), while the elision of the copy in the constructor `type y( f() );` is just *copy-elision*. Then again, I don't think there is any *precise authoritative* definition, but the second copy is not related to

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you just test it using whatever compiler you're interested in -- i.e., define X's copy constructor to have some side effect (eg printing a message), and see what the code you gave does for your compiler with your preferred optimization settings.